# What is an example of using Adaboost (Adaptive Boosting) approach with Decision Trees

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, adaboost

Is there any good tutorial that explains how to weight the samples during successive iterations of constructing the decision trees for a sample training set? I want to specifically how to the weights are assigned after the first decision tree is constructed.

Decision tree is designed using Information Gain as an anchor and I am wondering how is this affected due to the misclassifications in the previous iterations being weighted.

Any good tutorial /  example is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A Short Introduction to Boosting](http://www.yorku.ca/gisweb/eats4400/boost.pdf) from Freund and Schapire supplies an example of the AdaBoost algorithm using Quinlan's C4.5 Decision Tree model.